# Custom resolv.conf file

Tags: linux, redhat, linux-networking, reverse-dns, resolv.conf

Is there any way I can specify a custom `resolv.conf` file (instead of `/etc/resolv.conf`) in RedHat Linux, similar to specifying custom hosts file via `export HOSTALIASES=~/my_hosts`? I don't have root access to the server.

Background:
I need my `ldapsearch` command and `hosts` command to use my custom resolv.conf file instead of the default `/etc/resolv.conf` file

OS version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

Comment: Nope, it's systemwide and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's a path compiled into glibc, so your options are limited.** 

About the only solution I can think of (although I've never actually done this) would be to compile a custom resolver library to be used for your applications, and then run them with the `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/custom.resolver.library.so /path/to/your/app`. You would need to know how to build a custom resolver library first, of course.